# Sed variable substitution not working in a dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have set up as entrypoint for my docker image.
`CMD ["/bin/bash","/usr/local/sbin/wrapper.sh"]`
which contains

```
set -m
sed -i "s/DBPASSWORD/$DBPASSWORD/g" db_config.php
/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize &
/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

and then when I debug i see that

```
[root@edoc2-7bdc69555-ftbzt ctdocs]# cat db_config.php
<?php
$dbhost = "10.100.16.11";
$dbuser = "demo-docs";
$dbpass = "DBPASSWORD";
$db = "demodocsdb";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `RUN` before the `sed` command as following:

`RUN sed -i "s/DBPASSWORD/$DBPASSWORD/g" db_config.php`

Comment: You mean in the dockerfile?

Comment: Yes in the docerfile

Comment: I tried CMD and RUN both, unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

what I did was that I set up: set -x before the sed and it worked, thanks all for your help.